# How i can change images after click on button and php script ended?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How can I do this thing: I have php file with html code. On this page I have 8 images and 1 button.

- I pressed button
- POST request maked some php code and gave me back a random number between 1-8
- 7 images changing attr "src" to "empty"
- 1 image changing attr "src" to "full"

I don't need php code to make random and something like this. Please, tell me how can I change attr when I already get random number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery attr() change img src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986954/jquery-attr-change-img-src)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var rand = 3; // somehow get the random number from server via ajax
$('img').attr('src', 'empty');
$('img').eq(rand).attr('src', 'full');
```